# Android ArrayList iterator returns null

Tags: android, arraylist, iterator, nullpointerexception

I have a simple code below, where an [ArrayList](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html) iterator returns null when I am looping around the list. Does anyone have an idea what can cause the iterator to return null? Unfortunately i don't have the actual data, as this does happen only on other phones, I have no idea what is in allDisplayNames, but i know the list is initialized, as I check that it doesn't equal null.
Thanks in advance!

Here is the code:

```
            HashMap<Integer, List<String>> allDisplayNames = Contact
                    .getAllFullnames();
            ...
            for (Contact contact : Application.getContacts().values()) {
                ...
                ArrayList<String> namechunks = new ArrayList<String>();
                List<String> displaynames = new ArrayList<String>();
                displaynames.add(contact.getDisplay_name());
                if (allDisplayNames.get(contact.getId()) != null) {
                    displaynames.addAll(allDisplayNames.get(contact.getId()));
                }
                for (String string : displaynames) {
                    if (string==null) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    String[] temp = string.split(" "); <-- this line used to trigger NullPointer
                    ...
                }
```

Comment: contact.getDisplay_name() is returning null.

Comment: thank you, i tried it out and it turns out you can add null to an arraylist... the documentation says "permits all elements, including null".

Answer (score 0):

Here, exception is at `String[] temp = string.split(" ");` means `string` is null. So the ArrayList contains also null values.

 Possible solution is, Either do not add null values to your ArrayList, or change your null check as,

```
  if (string.equals(null)) {
       continue;
     }
```